# Order by conditional count of associated records

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, left-join, aggregate-functions

One `quiz` can have none, one or many `submissions`. Each `submission` has `submissions.correct = t` or `submissions.correct = f`.

What's the best Postgres 9.4 query to get all `quizzes` (regardless of whether they have a `Submission` or not), ordered by the number of associated `submissions` with `correct = t` in `ASC` order so that the `quizzes` that have the least amount of associated `submissions.correct = t` come first?

```
db=# \d quizzes;
                                         Table "public.quizzes"
       Column   |            Type             |                      Modifiers                       
    ------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------
     id         | integer                     | not null default nextval('quizzes_id_seq'::regclass)
     question   | character varying           | not null
     created_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
     updated_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
    Indexes:
        "quizzes_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    Referenced by:
        TABLE "submissions" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_04e433a811" FOREIGN KEY (quiz_id) REFERENCES quizzes(id)
        TABLE "answers" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_431b8a33a3" FOREIGN KEY (quiz_id) REFERENCES quizzes(id)

db=# \d submissions;
                                         Table "public.submissions"
       Column   |            Type             |                        Modifiers                         
    ------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------
     id         | integer                     | not null default nextval('submissions_id_seq'::regclass)
     quiz_id    | integer                     | not null
     correct    | boolean                     | not null
     created_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
     updated_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
    Indexes:
        "submissions_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
        "index_submissions_on_quiz_id" btree (quiz_id)
    Foreign-key constraints:
        "fk_rails_04e433a811" FOREIGN KEY (quiz_id) REFERENCES quizzes(id)
```

Comment: Very clear description and proper table definitions. If you also included your version of Postgres and what you tried so far (even if it's not working), this would be an exemplary question.

Comment: Thx. Version is Postgres 9.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT q.*, s.ct
FROM   quizzes q
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT quiz_id, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   submissions
   WHERE  correct
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) s ON s.quiz_id = q.id
ORDER BY s.ct NULLS FIRST;
```

- Since you want all quizzes, it's probably fastest to aggregate first and join later.
- Make it a `LEFT JOIN` to keep quizzes without submissions in the result.
- `NULLS FIRST` is crucial here, so that quizzes without any (correct) submissions come first.

  - [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)
- Unlike some other popular RDBMS, Postgres has a proper [`boolean`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-boolean.html) type. The expression `correct = t` is exactly the same as just `correct`.